# c# no me trae datos de la base de datos

Tags: c#, sql

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
                string cadena1 = "SELECT idSocio, nombre FROM Socios WHERE nombre = '" + cbSocio.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";
                SqlCommand comando1 = new SqlCommand(cadena1, conexion);
                conexion.Open();
                SqlDataReader leer1 = comando1.ExecuteReader();
                idSocio = leer1["idSocio"].ToString();
                int so = int.Parse(idSocio);
                leer1.Close();


                string cadena3 = "select idLibro,nombreLibro from Libros where nombreLibro = '" + cbLibro.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim() + "'";
                SqlCommand comando3 = new SqlCommand(cadena3, conexion);
                SqlDataReader leer3 = comando3.ExecuteReader();
                idLibro = leer3["idLibro"].ToString();
                int li = int.Parse(idLibro);


                string cadena2 = "insert into Alquiler(idAlquiler,idPeli,idSocio,fechaD,fechaH,precio) values ("+ li + "," + idSocio + "," + dateTimePicker1.Text.Trim() +"," + dateTimePicker2.Text.Trim() + "," + txtPrecio.ToString().Trim() + ")";
                SqlCommand comando2 = new SqlCommand(cadena2, conexion);
                comando2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Los datos se guardaron correctamente");
                conexion.Close();
```

Que me da el error que no trae datos. "Error de lectura porque no hay datos". En la linea 46 que es la:
**idSocio = leer1["idSocio"].ToString();**

Comment: https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/csharpya/index.php?inicio=60 A partir de esa página en adelante muestran tutoriales de interacción con bases de datos, espero te sea de utilidad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu codigo deberia ser algo como esto

```
conexion.Open();

int so, li;

string cadena1 = "SELECT idSocio, nombre FROM Socios WHERE nombre = @nombre";
SqlCommand comando1 = new SqlCommand(cadena1, conexion);
comando1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", cbSocio.SelectedItem.ToString() );
SqlDataReader leer1 = comando1.ExecuteReader();
if(leer1.Read())
{
    string idSocio = leer1["idSocio"].ToString();
    so = int.Parse(idSocio);
}


string cadena3 = "select idLibro,nombreLibro from Libros where nombreLibro = @nombre";
SqlCommand comando3 = new SqlCommand(cadena3, conexion);
comando3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", cbLibro.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim())
SqlDataReader leer3 = comando3.ExecuteReader();
if(leer3.Read())
{
    string idLibro = leer3["idLibro"].ToString();
    li = int.Parse(idLibro);
}


string cadena2 = @"insert into Alquiler(idAlquiler,idPeli,idSocio,fechaD,fechaH,precio) 
                    values (@idAlquiler, @idPeli, @idSocio, @fechaD, @fechaH, @precio)";
SqlCommand comando2 = new SqlCommand(cadena2, conexion);
comando2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idAlquiler", li);
comando2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idPeli", xxx);  //falta el valor de este parametro
comando2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idSocio", so);
comando2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fechaD", dateTimePicker1.Value);
comando2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fechaH", dateTimePicker2.Value);
comando2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@precio", Convert.ToDecimal(txtPrecio.Text));

comando2.ExecuteNonQuery();

MessageBox.Show("Los datos se guardaron correctamente");


conexion.Close();
```

Como veras

- Usa siempre parametros, concatenar los valores en un string son una mala practica
- debes evaluar el `Read()` para ver si hay registros, por eso use `if(leer1.Read()){ ...`
- Respeta los tipos de datos, si vas a persistir una fecha que el campo sea `datetime`, por lo tanto asigna ese mismo tiempo al parametro. Si vas a persistir un numero conviertelo a ese tipo de dato, no asignes un string donde debe ir un numero o fecha
- Te falto definir el parametro `idPeli`

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

te falto en el where = nombre

```
string cadena1 = "SELECT idSocio, nombre FROM Socios WHERE nombre = @nombre
```